# Where to put regular classes in Angular app?

Tags: angular

Assuming my app's structure looks like this:

```
|-- app
    |-- components
    |-- features
    |-- models
    |-- pipes
    |-- services
    |-- views
```

And now I've made a regular class with a few methods and `@Output` so that several components may extend this class. Should I create a folder "classes"? I've never seen this in the docs or articles.

Comment: `models` is what that's for normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has `@Output` as you say but it's not a component - I presume it's for other components to inherit? In this case I like to call them base components, I'll usually drop them within `components` a level higher than the inheriting components.

For example:

```
|-- app
    |-- components
        |-- fancy-table
            |-- small-fancy-table
                |-- small-fancy-table.component.ts
                |-- small-fancy-table.component.html
            |-- large-fancy-table
                |-- large-fancy-table.component.ts
                |-- large-fancy-table.component.html
            |-- base-fancy-table.component.ts <-- The class you're referring to.
    |-- features
    |-- models
    |-- pipes
    |-- services
    |-- views
```

Comment: In a folder or just like that?

Comment: You probably do want a folder to group them if it makes sense for the use case. If `my-base-component` is only used by components that happen to also be tables (for example) you'd have it within a `my-table` folder and use that for naming. `my-base-table.component.ts` etc. Updated the example to be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You already have models folder, you could create **`interface/class`** according to your need

Comment: If it has an `@Output` property and is inherited by components it's not a model imo.

Comment: Question is about regular classes! even if its @output you can have an object of that type

Comment: It has Output and methods

Comment: Sure you CAN but you won't be using the `@Output` unless it's used as a component. An `@Output` property on a model makes no sense at all.

Comment: I've only created interfaces in the models folder

Comment: yeah i do understand! then OP's approach is wrong, you usually do that inside a component not inside a class

Comment: I think it's okay to write a base component (which is OP's use case) that is not used as a component on its own, but instead inherited by multiple other components.

Comment: @Sajeetharan, several components will have next/back Outputs and methods. I don't want to repeat it every single time.